# Is dcterms:identifier an inverse functional property?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, dublin-core

To me, the `dcterms:identifier` property seems like a legitimate inverse functional property. When two things share the same identifier, I think it is safe to conclude that it is the same thing.

Is there any compelling reason not to define it as such (`owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`) in my ontology?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Rather, you ca make a separate ontology, import dcterms  and then create a sub-property of dcterms:identifier, which you can assert and use as `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`. Using a shared vocabulary like dcterms, would mean that there might be resources created by you linked to resources created by others. So there will be some resources using dcterms:identifier as `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`, and others not, creating various problems. (by the way `foaf:mbox` is `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to stay in OWL 2 DL, then it's not a good idea to declare data properties to be inverse functional - only object properties can be declared as such without violating the constraints and end up in OWL 2 FULL.

`dcterms:identifier` has a range of `rdfs:Literal` defined [here](http://wiki.dublincore.org/index.php/User_Guide/Publishing_Metadata#dcterms:identifier)

You could use a HasKey axiom to achieve similar results: keys were introduced in OWL 2 for the purpose of identifying one or more properties whose values are identifiers for the referring individuals, and both object and data properties can be used.